# background jobs' garbled output

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I'm trying to gather line by line the output of several child processes in a bash script, in order to forward it to another process.

I found nothing that guarantees that the outputs of the sub-processes are not mixed, but it's  important to me that each output line goes properly to the output. The order between the outputs does not matters.

Here's an example of mixed/garbled output:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..1000}; do
    ( { echo BEGIN; dmesg; echo END; } | tr -d '\n'; echo ) &
done

wait
```

Running this:

```
$ ./test_output.sh | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if m/(.{1,20}BEGIN.{0,20})/' | head
 0.000000] SRAT: PXMBEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
ME through PCIe PME BEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
ME through PCIe PME BEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
[    0.209816] pci 0BEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
ciehp 0000:00:16.1:pBEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
CI: Updating contextBEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
l family 2[    0.588BEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
ME through PCIe PME BEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
CI: Updating contextBEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
3922 pages, LIFO batBEGIN[    0.000000] Initi
```

You can see several line with mixed content.

Of course, without the `&` everything is fine.

So for now, I have no choice but to redirect every child's output to a file and then after a big `wait`, `cat` all these files.

Running the same with GNU parallel does part of the job, but it's not an option in my environment.

> GNU parallel makes sure output from the commands is the same output as
>   you would get had you run the commands sequentially. This makes it
>   possible to use output from GNU parallel as input for other programs.

So GNU parallel will write each job output as soon as each job is finished and it takes care of not mixing the output. That's good. But I would be also interested in getting the output of each job as soon as possible, ie not waiting for the job exit. There's the "-u" switch, but it will then mix the jobs output.

Do I need to play with fifo, select, or even write a perl script ?

--

I think i've found why/how/when the outputs get mixed in man 7 pipe

> POSIX.1-2001 says that write(2)s of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be
>   atomic: the output data is written to the pipe as a contiguous
>   sequence. Writes of more than PIPE_BUF bytes may be nonatomic: the
>   kernel may interleave the data with data written by other processes.
>   POSIX.1-2001 requires PIPE_BUF to be at least 512 bytes. (On Linux,
>   PIPE_BUF is 4096 bytes.)

Comment: Is it important that you get any output as soon as possible, or is it fine if you get it all once everything is finished?

Comment: I'd like to get it as soon as possible, yes. Otherwise, whether you store it in memory or a file per process, I think that's the same solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate why a 10 seconds install of GNU Parallel (wget -O - pi.dk/3 | sh) will not work? Is it covered by: http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Comment: Because I am not allowed to. And I think it wouldn't work with an ancient version of perl. I know that's stupid. I'm the one who found that it would solve my problem, but I can't use it on my target environment. Anyway, I think my question is interesting, the world hasn't waited for GNU parallel to solve this kind of issue, has it ?

Comment: Are you saying that your are not allowed to run a script that has proven to be of production quality, but you _are_ allowed to run your own scripts? So if GNU Parallel had been written by you, then it would have been OK? The only situation where I can see that makes sense is if your organisation has a strict code audit with different people auditing and testing the code. For GNU Parallel I looked at other solutions for separating output; the common problem was that the half-line issue was never dealt with correctly.

Comment: Strict organization or not, GNU Parallel is not the solution to my question :/ And my actual technical problem is that it won't run with an ancient perl on crappy OS. I'll try to come up with something and post it here then.

Comment: @OleTange Knowing that you are the author, maybe you can give some insight on how parallel ensures non-interleaved output.

Comment: GNU Parallel uses tempfiles stores in $TMPDIR.

Comment: I think I'm going to fall back on a simple IO::Select, have a simple script spawn all commands at once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my first draw. It's a simple script that starts all commands given on stdin in background (not sure that's what I want) and collects outputs from these, line by line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Select;
use POSIX qw(strftime);


my $SELECT_TIMEOUT = 1;
my $TAG_SEPARATOR = '|';
my $TAG_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S';


sub multiplex {
    my @commands = @_;
    my %tags = (); # fd -> cmd

    my $sel = IO::Select->new();

    for my $cmd (@commands) {
    $cmd =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

    my $fd;
    if (!open($fd, "-|", $cmd)) {
        warn "Cannot start '$cmd': $!";
        next;
    }
    else {
        $tags{$fd} = $cmd;
        $sel->add($fd);
    }
    }


    while ($sel->handles > 0) {
    my @handles = $sel->can_read($SELECT_TIMEOUT);

    # maybe something went wrong
    if (!@handles) {
        for my $fd ($sel->has_exception($SELECT_TIMEOUT)) {
        $sel->remove($fd);
        }
        next;
    }

    my $now = strftime($TAG_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT, localtime(time()));

    for my $fd (@handles) {
        if (defined(my $line = <$fd>)) {
        if ($TAG_SEPARATOR) {
            $line = join($TAG_SEPARATOR, $now, $tags{$fd}, $line);
        }
        print $line;
        }
        else {
        # EOF
        $sel->remove($fd);
        }
    }
    }
}




multiplex(<STDIN>);
```